# How to save a graphics image from QGraphicsScene in pyQT

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

How to render a graphics image from `QGraphicsScene` in pyQT

I have an image in `QGraphicsScene`, which is created from multiple `QGraphicsPixMapItem` items.

I need to render it out as a single image on disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would just get your combined bounding rect that you wish to capture, and then render it onto a `QPixmap`. You can save the `QPixmap` at that point.

Untested, but should be along the lines of...

```py
import operator

items = get_target_items() # just get all the items you want
# combine all the scene rects for the items
# equiv:   totalRect = rect1 | rect2 | ...
totalRect = reduce(operator.or_, (i.sceneBoundingRect() for i in items))

pix = QtGui.QPixmap(totalRect.width(), totalRect.height())
painter = QtGui.QPainter(pix)
scene.render(painter, totalRect)
pix.save("capture.jpg", "JPG")
```